# Slide Up Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I am trying to make a Slide Up Bottom Sheet as shown in the photo below(First shows what Im trying to make and the second what I have now). I've tried different ways and looked around SO and the web to see if there are any documentation on this and there doesn't seem to be much. The code I have below is the closest I can make it similar but something doesn't seem correct. Any help with the code to create this or any useful material would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            val sheet = DemoBottomSheetFragment()
            sheet.show(supportFragmentManager, "DemoBottomSheetFragment")
    }
}

class DemoBottomSheetFragment : SuperBottomSheetFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo_sheet, container, false)
    }

    override fun getCornerRadius() = context!!.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.demo_sheet_rounded_corner)

}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_demo_sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show_sheet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You have add searchview in bottom sheet layout and handle all search query there in bottom sheet fragments.

Comment: More so than the search bar, Im having problems with the bottom sheet layout

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? I have kotlin solution as well

Comment: @KaranMehta thanks for the response-I want to make something like the first picture(the google maps) slide up bottom sheet. If I could get the Kotlin solution, that would be great!

Comment: Please check answer @rengineer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use any constraint custom layout which you want and pass layout behaviour

```
   app:layout_behavior="app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior""
```

use in class file

use global variable

```
   private var mBottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*>? = null
```

In  on view created

```
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view);
     mBottomSheetBehavior?.peekHeight = 0
    setBottomSheetAndCallBackBottomSheetBehaviour();
    bottomSheetCollapsed();
    bottomSheet?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

and when create your view called method and pass your layout id and peek height is used for hide view first time.

```
/**
 * set bottom sheet behavior and state
 */
private fun setBottomSheetAndCallBackBottomSheetBehaviour() {


    mBottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN

    //callback
    mBottomSheetBehavior?.setBottomSheetCallback(object :
        BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                bottomSheetCollapsed()
            }
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
    })
}
```

and Use following method for expend and collapse.

```
 private fun bottomSheetExpand() {
    mBottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
}

private fun bottomSheetCollapsed() {
    mBottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
}
```

and on click of view use

```
  fun isExpendCollapse(){
     if (mBottomSheetBehavior?.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                bottomSheetExpand()
            } else {
                bottomSheetCollapsed()
            }
}
```

check xml file CoordinatorLayout is must for bottomsheet behaviour

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    >



<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_behavior="app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
   />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can constraint layout ,linear or any view instead of View. and ihave set cordinate layout with relative  layout(parent layout) , you can use as per your requirement.

Comment: my activity force close and re opening against if i access bottom behaviour with global variable only , , ,

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this :

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".activites.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFeedback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
        android:text="Feedback" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="444dp"
    android:background="#F0F0F1"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageClose"
    android:layout_width="34dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_close" />

    //Whatever controls you want to show in bottomsheet should be put here

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {

        btnFeedback.setOnClickListener(this)

        val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object :
            BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)
                }
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        when (v!!.id) {
            R.id.btnFeedback -> {
                val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet)
                if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED)

                } else {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
                }
            }

            R.id.imageClose -> {
                val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet)
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it says that BottomSheetBehavior isn't working. Any idea on what is causing the issue? Im getting "unresolved reference"

Comment: thanks for the help-I added the photo on the my original Post(it's the 3rd photo)

Comment: You just need to import BottomSheetBehavior and let me know if any problem

Comment: thanks-Sorry i tried importing as "import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" but this doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Import this : import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior                          in your activity

Comment: and add this dependency if you haven't : implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Comment: Then please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you

Comment: Sorry one last thing-the collapse portion when I click the image doesn't work-is there a way to "pull" the sheet down to make it back to its original position?

Comment: Yes, if you pull it down from the top portion it will collapse

Comment: It doesn't collapse when I pull it down from the top portion..can you please help